# Is it possible to navigate from WP7 app to the Device settings?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mobile-application

I'm developing an LBS application for WP7.

And i wondered, is it possible to check whether the location services is On?
Is it possible to navigate from within the app to the OS settings so the user could turn them on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can construct an instance of `GetCoordinateWatcher`.  If its `Status == GeoPositionStatux.Disabled` then the Location Service is not on.

You can't navigate to the Phone settings, so you will have to give a helpful description of the problem to the user and what they may choose to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation between applications is currently restricted to "tasks" ([Launchers and Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769542%28VS.92%29.aspx)), for which settings has no representative.

Interestingly it sits on top of a very generic (and very internal) Uri based navigation system that will hopefully be expanded upon for more inter-application navigation.